# Jenkins With Nginx Reverse Proxy And Resolver

Tags: nginx, jenkins, docker, proxy

I am running Jenkins inside Docker behind an Nginx reverse proxy. Now I got a problem with the resolver.

When I activate the resolver with:

```
set $backend "http://jenkins:8080/";
proxy_pass $backend;
```

I will get the following error for all javascript files:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost/static/....js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

When I simply proxy pass without resolver:

```
proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080/;
```

It works but without resolver. The resolver is mandatory otherwise the setup won't work when the host `jenkins` changes it's Ip (Docker DNS Server).

My configuration:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11  ipv6=off valid=30s;
client_max_body_size  100m;
keepalive_timeout     65;
types_hash_max_size   2048;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    location / {
        set $backend "http://jenkins:8080/";
        proxy_pass $backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: great question! :-)

Comment: thanks for upvote, accept, award; btw, for the future, you may want to hold on with the manual "award" part, as the question disappears from the featured tab, so, other people won't be able to note and vote on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message you receive, it sounds like you're getting HTML pages in place of JavaScript.

Using a [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) paradigm with a variable, you're telling nginx that it shouldn't mess with the value any further, e.g., regardless of the `location` and the URI, all requests to your backend will always be just as the variable says (e.g., with the same URI in your case).

---

The ***best option*** would probably be to use [`$uri`](http://nginx.org/r/$uri), [`$is_args`](http://nginx.org/r/$is_args) and [`$args`](http://nginx.org/r/$args), as per [NGINX proxy_pass remove path prefix & resolve DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218367/nginx-proxy-pass-remove-path-prefix-resolve-dns/33325584#33325584):

```
-        set $backend "http://jenkins:8080/";
-        proxy_pass $backend;
+        proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080$uri$is_args$args;
```

---

***Another option***, which potentially could be less secure, is to use [`$uri_request`](http://nginx.org/r/$uri_request), which has a slightly different meaning than the plain `$uri` in certain limited cases, as per [Nginx pass_proxy subdirectory without url decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684300/nginx-pass-proxy-subdirectory-without-url-decoding/37584637#37584637):

```
proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080$request_uri;
```

Comment: Why not `proxy_pass $backend$uri$is_args$args;` ?

Comment: @maybeg, either variant should work; but if you use the variable in a single context, code may look cleaner and more understandable without it (otherwise, someone might think that your variable has a special meaning). Also, consider that the proper way to define an upstream "variable" is with the [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/r/upstream) directive, although the `server` `resolve` part in that context is a non-OSS feature, so, won't work for you, unless you have a subscription.