# Nginx: Forward request to a sub folder under a specific port without changing URL

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to forward `http://example.com` to `http://example.com:5000/foo`?

I tried using proxy_pass to forward requests to port 5000:

```
location / { 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
}
```

Which works as expected. However, if I want to forward requests to `/foo`, I can't just change the proxy_pass to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo/` since it wouldn't be able to find the static files.

So I then tried to use `try_files` in hopes to serve the static files correctly:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /foo/;
}

location /foo/ { 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
}
```

But that wouldn't work either since the resources are under port 5000. Any help?

Comment: Can you change the application running on port 5000 to expect the base url as `/foo`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't think that's an option since I'll have multiple sub folders on port 5000 that I'd want to forward to

Comment: Then you would need to do something like below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610662/nginx-reverse-proxy-with-different-context-path/46612478#46612478